# How can we make a redirect in .htaccess for the “git” project?

Tags: git, apache, .htaccess, redirect

There is a project on “git”. There is also a hosting service and the document_root refers to http_public. We have no possible way to change it.

I clone the repository into http_public, the web-tool is located at http_public/zzz.

redirect htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^zzz
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ zzz/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

When we refer to the website example.com, my web-tool is being opened.

**How can we make the website work by referring to example.com but not working directly from example.com/zzz/?**

Comment: what you mean by **but not working directly from example.com/zzz/?**

Comment: They want to show example.com not example.com/zzz but it should still load from that location, imo - something like a hack fix for setting document root to http_public/zzz.

Comment: example.com - yes
example.com/zzz/ - no (or redirect on example.com)

Comment: Depending on the structure and workflow of your website, you might be able to make an entry script in http_public which loads the files from http_public/zzz without redirecting. You will also have to use full paths instead of relative(or correct the latter to represent the correct structure) so this can work.